# Incorrect plot with pgfplots and gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I'm attempting to plot `atanh(x)` although there seems to be a giant straight line linking the top and bottom points. Am I doing something wrong?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[no markers,samples=1001]
    \addplot gnuplot{atanh(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should probably limit the domain to avoid winding back which seems the case here.

Comment: Indeed, adding `,domain=-0.99:0.99` to the options helps.

Comment: @percusse Please make that an answer.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the reminder, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A – perhaps unsatisfactory – solution could be to restrict the *y* values to a certain domain.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      no markers,
      samples=1000,
      restrict y to domain=-2:2
    ]
      \addplot gnuplot{atanh(x)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Derived from Section 4.21 of the »[pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)« manual (p. 272).

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not a problem with `gnuplot` because `tkz-fct` uses  `gnuplot` and I get

[image]

with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzInit[xmin=-1,xmax=1,xstep=.2,
          ymin=-5,ymax=5,ystep=1]
 \tkzGrid[color=brown,sub,subxstep=.1](-1,-5)(1,5)
 \tkzAxeXY
 \tkzFct[color=red,samples=1001,domain = -1:1]%
    {atanh(\x)}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Perhaps there is an option in pgfplots to avoid this problem. The author of pgfplots Christian F. will surely help you.

Comment: `gnuplot` marks the point `0,0` as invalid in the `.tkzfct.table` (and in the `.pgf-plot.table`) with an `i` in the third column. It seems that `tkz-fct` (and plain TikZ/PGF) uses that column to exclude the point from the plot, while `pgfplots` does not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a comparison of different ways of doing the same job with the resulting tables as Jake commented:

First, let's draw a few atanh(x) plots

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[no markers,samples=202,restrict y to domain=-2:2]
\addplot[id=atanh1] gnuplot{atanh(x)};
\end{axis}

\begin{scope}[domain=-2:2,shift={(10,2.5)}]
\draw[ultra thick,red] plot[raw gnuplot,id=raw-example] function{set samples 202; plot atanh(x)};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-7)}]
\begin{axis}[no markers,samples=202,domain=-0.999:0.999]
    \addplot[id=atanh1] gnuplot{atanh(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I wan't to emphasize here is along the lines of Jake's comment. If you look at the resulting `.table` files of the first two methods, most of the sampling points are discarded and even in the original `pgfplots` part it's drawn with lines to origin. Here is the snapshot from the `.table` file of the `raw-example`. `u` and `i` are the identifiers that confuses `pgfplots` and it draws them anyway.

[image]

As we can see only a limited number of points are of interest and the rest is either outside the domain of the function `-1<x<1` or numerical noise which is the reason why I manually tuned to 202 samples. However in my last example I restrict the domain of the function such that all samples are valid and increases the resolution.

Long story short, it's not a good idea to rely on the plotter's abilities for identifying the domain of the function and filtering them, which would result in dummy sampling points , increased compile time and incerased file sizes for no good reason. Although, `gnuplot` and `pgfplots` are marvellous tools, we should help them a little anyway :)