# pgfplots: plotting data with gnuplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I try to plot a data file (test2) which contains a header and 2 columns.

My pdfLaTeX (argument: --enable-write18) gives me not the result I get with executing gnuplot.exe.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[paperwidth=27cm,paperheight=17cm,margin=0in,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}



\begin{document}



\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
    width=21cm, height=14cm,
    tick label style={font=\large},
%   xmin=7700, xmax=7810,
%   xtick={7700,7725,...,7800},
%   ymin=0.009, ymax=0.05,
    axis x line=box,
    axis y line=box
    ]
    \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot, id=test, mark=none, color=blue]{
%   set xrange [7700:7810];
%   set yrange [0:0.05];
    plot "test2" using ($1):($2) every 1:1:139000::144100 with lines; %plot intervall: max. 7600
    };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Obtained in Latex:[image: pdfLaTeX Output]

But only in gnuplot I get the result I am looking for:

[image: GnuPlot]

The Code is the same: "plot "test2" using ($1):($2) every 1:1:139000::144100 with lines", what am I doing wrong?

The data file is aviable here: http://www.file-upload.net/download-7765589/test2.html

I am looking forward for your advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `restrict y to domain=0.005:0.045` to your axis environment (see [Incorrect plot with pgfplots and gnuplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51989/incorrect-plot-with-pgfplots-and-gnuplot))

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[paperwidth=27cm,paperheight=17cm,margin=0in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
    width=21cm, height=14cm,
    tick label style={font=\large},
    axis x line=box,
    axis y line=box,
            restrict y to domain=0.005:0.045
    ]
    \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot, id=test, mark=none, color=blue]{
    plot "test2" using ($1):($2) every 1:1:139000::144100 with lines; %plot intervall: max. 7600
    };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]